# Publishing android application on android Market

Tags: android

I have a requirement for an android application whereby the application is sold as modules.
In summary the application will have 3 modules and users can choose to buy 1, 2 or all of the 3 modules.
For example user A can choose to buy only module 1 where he gets only features A and B. User B buys 2 modules and he gets Features A, B, C,D and user C buys all 3 modules and they get all the features of the whole application.

The 3 modules all pertain to the same application.

How can we implement the licensing for this type of application so that the user can choose to buy 1, 2 or all 3 modules. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you could create one free application and then let the user purchase the different modules or module-combinations using androids [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the installed package, I use this in one of mine where a barcode scanner is nessesary:

```
public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String BARCODE_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

        if (checkForBarcodeApp() == false) {
            Button installBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Install);
            installBtn.setOnClickListener(mInstall);
            installBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TextView installTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Install);
            installTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            Button installBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Install);
            installBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            TextView installTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Install);
            installTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    public final Button.OnClickListener mScanQRCode = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            checkForBarcodeApp();
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You need to install the barcode scanner first",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```